Adress of an l-value
I am trying to follow DirectX 12 guidebook (Introduction to 3D Game Programming). In there there is this code:
_device->CreateCommittedResource(
        &CD3DX12_HEAP_PROPERTIES(D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_DEFAULT),
        D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE,
        &CD3DX12_RESOURCE_DESC::Buffer(byteSize),
        D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COMMON,
        nullptr,
        IID_PPV_ARGS(defaultBuffer));

When I try to reproduce this code in my project, I get this error: C2102 '&' requires l-value. I have brief understanding of all r/l -value stuff (though I am no expert). Function signature:
HRESULT CreateCommittedResource( 
const D3D12_HEAP_PROPERTIES *pHeapProperties,
D3D12_HEAP_FLAGS HeapFlags,            
const D3D12_RESOURCE_DESC *pDesc,             
D3D12_RESOURCE_STATES InitialResourceState,
const D3D12_CLEAR_VALUE *pOptimizedClearValue, 
REFIID riidResource,
void **ppvResource) 

The error, obviously, is about the 1st and the 3rd parameters.
As far as I understand, calling a class constructor within function call scope creates a temporary value which expires as soon as the the execution flow moves to the called function body, so using a pointer to it within the function body is wrong (it "points" to a destructed value).
What's more surprising, I have obtained the guidebook sample code and compiled it and it's OK, there are no errors. Moreover, the program runs OK (everything is drawn properly), so my thoughts on dangling pointer were wrong. I want to understand the thing and hear opinion from an experienced coder.
I suspect that maybe some errors have been suppresed via ProjectSettings. Or else, it has to do something with out-dated SDK version or older compiler (v140) I had to install to run the sample. I can apply sample code if necessary.

CD3DX12_HEAP_PROPERTIES(D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_DEFAULT) is a temporary value, and you can't take address of it. Microsoft compiler supports taking address of a temporary as an extension. Previously, it was enabled by default, but since a certain version it should be enabled explicitly. The book assumes some old compiler version is used. To solve the problem, assign that value to a local variable and then take address of the variable.

It took you much less words to confirm my suspicions and answer my quention than me to ask it. Thank you!

I added some dupes with more detailed explanations.

Thanks. I looked through. However, diabling conformance (i.e. setting Conformance mode to No(/permissive)) did not solve the issue.

@SigmaKlim You need to use /permissive- flag instead of the /permissive. Note the former has - at the end while the latter does not.

It turned out it was It was set so initially...

I get that the best solution is to create a local variable. However, want to understand how to enable addressing temp variable as well.

Double check that you indeed have this setting enabled for the current build type and the current platform. And try to compile this simple code in your project: https://godbolt.org/z/TvY6PY1cx

It does not build, no matter which conformant mode is set...

& is the opposite of dereference here, it is address-of

My suggestion would be to create a new project and try to compile sample code I posted above. If it doesn't compile with /permissive flag, please create a new question, specify exact VS version number, add that sample code and maybe add a screenshot of project settings. I can't reproduce this error neither on my local VS nor on Godbolt.
